# Angular 2 how to ignore .map.js files?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gitignore

I would like to now how to ignore all .js.map files in angular 2. In my .gitignore file all I have already tried all the possibilities but did not work yet.

```
*.log
typings
src/app/**/*.js
src/app/**/*.map
node_modules
.idea/
src/app/**/**/*.map
src/app/*.map
src/app/**/*.js.map
src/app/**/*.js
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried '*. map'?

Comment: try this **/*.map

Comment: @YoavSchniederman I try this right now, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE THESE

```
**/*.map 
**/app/**/*.js
```